# Two copy of Java in JWS

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

I am working with Java web start. After launching application with Java web start, it checks for java environment in our system. If required java version is not found, then it downloads appropriate version to our system for that application only,but not affecting the system environment.

My question is that if in my system there are Java1.3. and I am
launching 2 or more than 2 different applications using Java web
start,which all required java 1.6 . Then are they all downloads
different copies of java? If yes,then there is any way that only one
copy of java should get downloaded.

Comment: why would you keep java 1.3 on your system? can't you upgrade?

Comment: I am given just a example here of java 1.3. if anyone have lower version of java then required by the Java web start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then are they all downloads different copies of java?

No.

Comment: thanks for reply.
Then how it works? As I know JNLP file checks for java in our system.if java is not found or lower then required then download it.

Comment: @Ronak It installs different versions, but it doesn't install a copy of each version per application.